# DataURL not returning value

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, local-storage, data-uri

I have created a function that stores DataURI of image in local storage.

Data is stored perfectly in the local storage but if I try to get value from function i.e. return statement, then I get "undefined" value.
Probably, the function is returning value before even converting to dataURL.

Need your help.

Here is my code:

```
function getImageDataURL(local_name,w,h,i){    
var data, canvas, ctx;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){      
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h);
    try{
        data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        localStorage.setItem(local_name,data);
    }catch(e){
        console.log("error "+e)
    }
}
try{
    img.src = i;
}catch(e){}
return data;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking an asynchronous value and trying to return it synchronously. `img.onload` is being called way after the function returns. A common pattern in JavaScript is to pass the function another function to call when its done:

```
function getImageDataURL(local_name, w, h, i, callback) {    
    var data, canvas, ctx;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function (){      
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h);

        callback(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    }
    img.src = i;
}

getImageDataURL('image', 100, 100, 'image.png', function (data) {
    localStorage.setItem(local_name, data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

One problem you might run into is a cross-domain security feature. If you draw an image from a foreign domain (that is, one that's different from the page with the JavaScript), it will "taint" the canvas, and you're no longer able to access the image data using `toDataURL`.

To bypass this, you'll either need to get the remote server to implement CORS approval or run a proxy server so it looks like the image is coming from your own server.